# Groovy LinkedHashMap --- strange notation

Tags: grails, groovy

I found the following Groovy code. Does anyone knows what it does mean the `rows column` notation? How can I make use of the "mapping"?

```
class TextAreaView {

  Integer rows
  Integer cols

  static mapping = {
    rows column: "rows_size"
    cols column: "cols_size"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "make use of the mapping"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a grails domain class mapped onto custom fields in the database.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames

You don't use it directly.

The format is basically passing a map to a method.

If you add parentheses, it would look like:

```
rows( [ column:'rows_size' ] )
```